# Does arquillian support the new chrome headless mode?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

Does anyone know if arquillian graphene support the new chrome headless mode? see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless

Currently i'm setting it like below and can't tell if its using the new or old mode

`-Darq.extension.webdriver.browser=chromeheadless`

or does someone have a workaround so i can set the following

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
```